# can i logically control finalize() method to run or not in java

Tags: java

Can I logically control finalize() method to run or not in java ?
I want to run finalize() method depending on the result returned from a conditional method.

Comment: why can't you add the same condition in the finalize method ?

Comment: why do you want to run it? need?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I logically control finalize() method to run or not in java ?

Answer is you cannot.

> I want to run finalize() method depending on the result returned from
>   a conditional method.

You can use the condition or a flag check in your finalize to decide whether you want to do the cleanup or not.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Calls `Asynchronously` when `GC` started cleanup.

See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29)  on same,

> Called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object. A subclass overrides the finalize method to dispose of system resources or to perform other cleanup.

But doing cleanup(or some logic) in the finalize seems little design flaw to me.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try
Runtime.getRuntime().runFinalizersOnExit(boolean value)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly you can't control finalize method. It all depends upon JVM logic.
At the most you can only call System.gc(); to request JVM to run Garbage Collector but again it will purely depend upon JVM algorithm whether to run it or not.

Finalize method is just an option to do some manipulations if your object is going to be garbage collected at any point of time but not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to do custom tasks you can override finalize method. But it is best not to rely on it.